# SQL Server: Using multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 distinct joins that I'm not sure how to put together in 1 query. Both queries pull correctly in that it pulls info from `PROVIDERS` with the first joining `PostalCodes`'s county to city. The 2nd query joins only providers with 'general acute care hospital' from table `Taxonomy`

What is the proper way to correctly use both these joins in 1 query? Please let me know if I am missing any crucial information with my quesetion.

query 1 to join `PostalCodes.County`

```
 SELECT     PROVIDERS.ProviderID, PROVIDERS.NAME, PROVIDERS.CITY, PROVIDERS.STATE, PROVIDERS.ZIP, PostalCodes.County                  
FROM  PostalCodes INNER JOIN
                    PROVIDERS ON PostalCodes.City = PROVIDERS.CITY
WHERE     (1=1)
AND (PROVIDERS.STATE = 'AL')
```

query 2 to join `Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Specialization]`

```
  SELECT     PROVIDERS.ProviderID, PROVIDERS.NAME, PROVIDERS.CITY, PROVIDERS.STATE, PROVIDERS.ZIP, NPI.[Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] as "ADDRESS"                                      
FROM               
                    Taxonomy INNER JOIN
                      NPI_Taxonomy ON Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Code] = NPI_Taxonomy.[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code] 
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS ON NPI_Taxonomy.NPI = PROVIDERS.FACILITYID
                      right outer join npi on PROVIDERS.FACILITYID = NPI.NPI
WHERE     (1=1)
AND (PROVIDERS.STATE = 'AL')
AND ([Taxonomy Specialization] like 'general acute care hospital')
```

Comment: For readability I'd use a Common Table expression. and it avoids having to really think about those pesky outer joins as both queries have been materialized. before our joins (assuming on provider)

Comment: Just curious, what's the point of specifying `WHERE 1=1`?

Comment: likely a dynamically built query and doing this is easier than figuring out if a limiting criteria has already been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH POSTALPROVIDERS AS 
(SELECT PROVIDERS.ProviderID, PROVIDERS.NAME, PROVIDERS.CITY, PROVIDERS.STATE, PROVIDERS.ZIP, PostalCodes.County                  
FROM  PostalCodes 
INNER JOIN PROVIDERS 
  ON PostalCodes.City = PROVIDERS.CITY
WHERE (1=1)
  AND (PROVIDERS.STATE = 'AL')),

TAXONOMY2 as 
( SELECT PROVIDERS.ProviderID, PROVIDERS.NAME, PROVIDERS.CITY, PROVIDERS.STATE, PROVIDERS.ZIP, NPI.[Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] as "ADDRESS"                                      
FROM Taxonomy 
INNER JOIN NPI_Taxonomy ON Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Code] = NPI_Taxonomy.[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code] 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS 
 ON NPI_Taxonomy.NPI = PROVIDERS.FACILITYID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN npi 
 on PROVIDERS.FACILITYID = NPI.NPI
WHERE 1=1)
AND (PROVIDERS.STATE = 'AL')
AND ([Taxonomy Specialization] like 'general acute care hospital'))

SELECT * 
FROM POSTALPROVIDERS PP
INNER JOIN TAXONOMY2 T
 ON PP.PROVIDERID = T.ProviderID
```

But if you must for performance reasons: this may do it.... setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and I'll ensure they work.

```
SELECT p.ProviderID, P.NAME, P.CITY, P.STATE, P.ZIP, PC.County,  NPI.[Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] as "ADDRESS"
FROM  PostalCodes PC
INNER JOIN PROVIDERS  P
  ON PC.City = P.CITY
LEFT JOIN NPI_Taxonomy NT
 on NT.NPI = P.FacilityID
LEFT JOIN Taxonomy T
  ON Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Code] = NPI_Taxonomy.[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code] 
 AND ([Taxonomy Specialization] like 'general acute care hospital'))
WHERE (1=1)
  AND (P.STATE = 'AL')
```

We have to move the limiting criteria on taxonomy to the join criteria otherwise we will lose providers and postal codes when the join to NPI_Taxonomy doesn't exist.

Assumption here is you want all providers and postal codes in AL and any related taxonomy information that exists but keep all the provider and postal codes if no taxonomy information is found.

This is done by joining proviers to postal codes as both queries indicated. then left joining in the NPI_taxonomy and taxonomy.  We have to move the where clause of the taxonomy to the join or lose the provider information.

Comment: Getting some errors in the "2nd query" and final select.http://i.imgur.com/8yMeXfv.png. First is `Recurssive common table expression 'Taxonmy' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL expression.` The rest are invalid column, object, or could not be bound.

Comment: that will teach me to use a CTE name (taxonomy) the same as a table inside (taxonomy).  I renamed the taxonomy cte to taxonomy2 to avoid the recursive query. oh and I had `tax npi_taxonomy` on the first left join  it should have just been `npi_taxonomy`

Comment: Incidentally, when troubleshooting CTE's ensure each query works independently before focusing on the whole.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. I think I got what I needed. I'm getting errors in the 2nd query still though and a "(" went missing the WHERE clause in the first query.

Comment: @user3749447 What errors or is accepting the answer indicating you have what you need?